# WooCommerce SQL Query to Show Customers Total Order Between Dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Struggling a little bit here getting the output correct for an SQL query I'm writing to pull out the ID of the customer, total tax and order total. At the moment I've got it pulling out each order individually, but when I group by customer_id it doesn't add all the totals up as I expect

```
SELECT
    SUM( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS order_total,
    SUM( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS order_tax,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS customer_id
FROM
    wp_posts p 
    join wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
WHERE
    post_type = 'shop_order' AND
    post_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-07-08' AND
    post_status = 'wc-completed' 
GROUP BY
    p.ID
```

I replace p.ID with:

```
CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END
```

But i get the following (which isnt correct)

```
   Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_total] => 428984.019999999
        [order_tax] => 71247.3400000001
        [customer_id] => 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_total] => 
        [order_tax] => 
        [customer_id] => 15
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_total] => 
        [order_tax] => 
        [customer_id] => 16
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_total] => 
        [order_tax] => 
        [customer_id] => 19
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_total] => 
        [order_tax] => 
        [customer_id] => 23
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on your question as I had a similar problem I was trying to solve. So after a lot of experimentation my solution adapted to your problem is:

```
select distinct 
  pm1.meta_value as customer_id,
  sum( pm2.meta_value ) as order_total,
  sum( pm3.meta_value ) as order_tax
from wp_posts as p
  join wp_postmeta as pm1
    on p.ID = pm1.post_id
  join wp_postmeta as pm2
    on pm2.post_id = p.ID
  join wp_postmeta as pm3
    on pm3.post_id = p.ID
where
  p.post_type = 'shop_order' and
  p.post_status ='wc-completed' and
  date(p.post_date) between '2015-01-01' and '2016-07-08' and
  pm1.meta_key = '_customer_user' and
  pm2.meta_key = '_order_total' and
  pm3.meta_key = '_order_tax'
group by customer_id;
```

This query should give you more sensible data.

One notable correction to your query is that post_date is a datetime field so it needs to be converted to date only value. You could always define your date values as: '2015-01-01 00:00:00'

The query is sensitive to missing or duplicate data in the wp_postmeta table. In my data set (some of it was migrated from a different ecom platform) some orders had missing or duplicate meta_keys.

Duplicate meta_keys caused rows to be duplicated and using `select distinct` deals with it nicely.

Missing meta_keys causes the order to be excluded from the results and I couldn't find a simple solution to deal with this. I tried using `left join` to include null values but the queries got hugely complex.

I eventually resorted to running two separate SQL queries to deal with the missing orders and then combining the results in the main code body.

Something you should be aware of is that `_customer_user` returns only customers that have Wordpress user accounts. All guest orders will be lumped under user id 0. In my use case I used the billing email address to group customers by as the vast majority of orders are guest customers.